# Time complexity of Arrays.equals()

Tags: java, arrays, char, equals, time-complexity

I have two `char` arrays generated from two strings.I would like to determine whether the arrays are equals.

```
str1Array = str1.toCharArray();
str2Array = str2.toCharArray();
```

My understanding is that `str1Array.equals(str2Array)` will only return `true` when the array objects are the same object in memory. If I want to check whether each of the indices are the same, I should use `Arrays.equals(str1Array, str2Array)`

I am wondering about the complexity of this equals method.

I assume it cannot be `O(1)` because it is not able to evaluate the content equality of the array objects without checking equality for each index. My guess is that it is `O(n)` where `n` corresponds to the `min(str1Array.length, str2Array.length)`

Can anyone verify this or comment otherwise?

Comment: You can look at the source code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This site it meant to be a reference. Comments like that don't really help. Sure, I agree with you, but an answer would be a lot more effective. We want to be looked up, we don't want to tell people to look things up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, let's look at the source code:

```
public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        Object o1 = a[i];
        Object o2 = a2[i];
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

(It's about the same for the other variations of the method).

As we can see, it's iterating through the array. So it has a worst-case complexity of `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the arrays compared. (If the arrays are different sizes, then it exits immediately, making it `O(1)`).

However, it doesn't always take that long. It does have some preconditions for equality, a null check, and a length check. It also exits as soon as a match is found, so it could take a lot less time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized I didn't install the source code when I set up my jdk. Reinstalling now.

Comment: @BrianVanover It's somewhere in the installation directory, it's named `src.zip`.